# Total of PowerBI matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to make Totals in powerBI matrix to be not SUMmed for each column?

I have a percentage measure which says which project made which ratio of revenue out of whole portfolio for each month, but the % are SUMmed for Total.

Example:

[image: Total]

Is there a way how to put average of % instead of SUM in Total?

Measure I am using:

```
Klient/Portfolio Ratio =
DIVIDE(
    'POHODA EXPORT'[SUMX(price)];
    'POHODA EXPORT'[MeasurePortfolio]
)
```

When MeasurePortfolio is:

```
MeasurePortfolio =
CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        DISTINCT('POHODA EXPORT'[Concatenate]);
        FIRSTNONBLANK(
            'POHODA EXPORT'[Suma Portfolio];
            0
        )
    ) / DISTINCTCOUNT('POHODA EXPORT'[Concatenate])
)
```

and Suma Portfolio is a column calculated as:

```
Suma Portfolio = 
var PM1 ='POHODA EXPORT'[PMs.PM]
var month1 = MONTH('POHODA EXPORT'[1.MM.YYYY])
var year1 = YEAR('POHODA EXPORT'[1.MM.YYYY])
return
CALCULATE(
    SUM('POHODA EXPORT'[Suma bez DPH]);
    FILTER(
        'POHODA EXPORT';
        'POHODA EXPORT'[PMs.PM] = PM1
            && MONTH('POHODA EXPORT'[1.MM.YYYY]) = month1
            && YEAR('POHODA EXPORT'[1.MM.YYYY]) = year1
    )
)
```

Concatenate is a column which makes a unique reference from Month, Year and Project Manager to able to proceed with requirements.

What I am trying to achieve is out of data certain PM has assigned portfolio of projects, and get them a ratio percentage for project/portfolio.

Mentioned formulas works succesfully, but then Subtotal has a wrong value, when Subtotal SUMS percentage for each month instead of averaging them, so for one project it make the percentage 400% Subtotal.

I don`t understand the logic how Subtotal is calculated, I calculate project Margin in percentage, but % for each month is not SUMmed in Total.
And also there are calculations using measures and columns.
I tried to google but not succesfully.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to include the measure formula you are using.

Answer (score 1):

To get

> average of % instead of SUM in Total

you should calculate the average, not the division.
In your realization *Total* value actually divides **annual 'POHODA EXPORT'[SUMX(price)]** by **annual 'POHODA EXPORT'[MeasurePortfolio]**.

Try to put your measure inside an `AVERAGE()` function like:

```
Average Measure = 
AVERAGE([Your Measure])
```

The hint is that the average of monthly value is monthly value! So replacing your measure with this measure will have no affect to monthly values in matrix, but the total will be calculated correctly.
Using additional function will slow down your report so use this advice wisely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your description, but I expect your issue is using a SUM in the expression inside a SUMX function.  Within any ...X function, the expression to be calculated for each row should always be a naked column reference or a measure, to avoid weird results like these.  Your can create a measure to just to the SUM, and reference that and it starts working as you would expect.

I don't know why, it just is. There are many gotchas like this in DAX, where the default behaviour is counterintuitive.

Comment: I try to explain little more, I got java code to export data out of accounting system, its stored to server out of which PowerBI is getting the data. The most important data are Invoice amount, Month, Project and Project Manager. Afterwards I am reporting revenue for each month for each project(when all PM`s have separate pbix file for their portfolio). New requirement has been to add ratio between project to whole portfolio of their projects. For this purpose I am using above described formulas. Only problem is with the total. I tried SUM before, but after reading this article I tried SUMX.

Comment: If you would need more description, please let me know what about :) Meanwhile I am going to try your advice. Article: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/use-sum-vs-sumx/